# Как правильно делать деплой через docker-compose?

Tags: linux, docker

У меня есть такой файл с настройками `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: service nginx start
    ports:
      - "35001:80"
```

Он собирает все правильно, но я не могу понять как правильно делать деплой на удаленную машину.

Вот все вопросы:

- Где необходимо указать хосты и порты для `ssh` подключения?
- Какие настройки должны быть на удаленной машине ?
- Как мне запустить через `docker-compose` контейнер с флагами `-d` и
  `--name`, чтобы контейнер сразу начал выполнять свои обязаности ?

В [официальной документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) на примере `Django` не нашел ответы на свои вопросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docker-compose  python утилита для сборки docker контейнеров, позволяющая запускать одновременно несколько контейнеров, используя при этом единый файл конфигурации всего стека сервисов, нужных вашему приложению.

т.е необходимо вручную подключится на сервер, установить докер, скопировать свой compose файл на сервер, и на сервере выполнить docker-compose up -d

(небольшой туториал http://video4text.com/en/K4H0_xdMvPY.html)

Comment: А как обычно все это деплоится ?

Comment: есть 2а варианта
1) если вам нужно в композ завернуть какой либо свой проект (веб сервер) - то вы в гит репозиторий проекта помещаете файл docker-compose
после на сервере git clone my_project && cd my_project && docker-compose up -d
* после перезагрузки сервера контейнеры будут стартовать автоматически

Comment: 2) еще есть возможность на основе созданого контейнера создать образ и сохранить его на докер-хаб (для публичных образов бесплатно); а если вам нужна автоматизация настройки сервера по ssh - то используйте fabric скрипты; (еще некоторые облачные провайдеры позволяют создать сервер на основе docker-compose скрипта)

Comment: я обычно в репозиторий с проектом добовляют dockerfile, docker-compose, (если нужна автоматизация то и fabric) - что бы самому, или заказчику было легко развернуть проект на сервере;

Comment: А почему после перезагрузки контейнеры будет стартовать автоматически ? Ведь `docker-compose` не демон.

Comment: >А почему после перезагрузки контейнеры будет стартовать >автоматически ? Ведь docker-compose не демон

@faoxis

так dockerd демон - docker-compose тупой скрипт юзающий docker команды, а тот в свою очередь работает через сокет с dockerd. добавив опцию **restart: always** получаем автоматический запуск после reboot'а или падения